# Where to administer apache fallback directory

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I have been put in charge of an Ubuntu 13 server installation. Apache is configured to use /var/www as the default directory which is correct. The issue is that it seems there is a fallback directory configured that points to /usr/share. So if I type into a browser (www.address.com) it will serve the documents out of /var/www, but if I know the name of a directory in /usr/share and type in (www.address.com/sharedir) then it will serve out of the /usr/share directory. I have looked in the apache config file and default site config file and do not see this association. I do not want this behavior and am concerned that this is the default behavior out of the box.

Can anyone guide me to another areas where this behavior may be controlled/managed.
Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Open your

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

file and replace

> /var/www

to

> /path/to/folder/you/wish

save and it will be better to restart apache by

> service apache2 restart

Now put website contents to the new location /path/to/folder/you/wish.

Once you changed the Document root of the of the site as mentioned above, Then no files will be fetched from any other location. Hopes this will help you. :)

Comment: Thanks for responding but I'm not sure you're understanding the behavior I am running into. I am not having issues with configuring the root directory. The issue is that Apache is falling back to another directory if the requested resource is not in the configured root. Example:  File '/var/www/indexA.html' can be accessed with example.com/indexA.html. But if I type in example.com/indexB.html and indexB.html is NOT in '/var/www' then it looks/serves it out of '/usr/share/indexB.html'.  Why does it fall back to anything and not just throw a 404, and where do I adjust this?

Comment: Yeah. I got an image of your issue now. If apache is looking for /usr/share/ in case if the files not in /var/www/, make sure that there is no soft link or hard link between these directories back and forth. Also try to check if there any entries for /usr/share in any apache included files I mean /etc/apache/*. You can check that with the help of grep command with options -iRl. AFAIK if you changes the document root to something else, then the possibilities regarding the soft or hard link can be sorted. All d best ahead :)

Comment: Ohh.. I didn't noticed your above update that issue has been solved. Glad to hear that your issue has been resolved. Could u explain me the changes you have made apart from the update you have made above as I am lil curious to know the fix :)

Comment: For whatever reason the previous '?admin?' put .config files that would be normally reserved for the 'apache/active-sites' directory in 2 different locations, 'conf.d' and 'mods-enabled. Not sure why Apache picked them up but all I did was remove them then the oddball routing went away. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] After a bunch more digging around I discovered that the user that originally set up this server erroneously put .conf files in the 'conf.d' directory and 'mods-enabled' directory that were routing traffic to the other directories. Sorry to anyone that noodled on this one.